# What is the difference between ∈ and ⊆?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I know that ∈ is a member of. such as: x∈ℝ meaning x is a member of the real numbers.

But ⊆ appears in the same context and i dont understand how they are different.

for example in graph theory the definition of a subgraph and neighborhood the symbols both appear but i dont understand why ∈ isnt just used?

"A subgraph G’ = (V’ , E’ ) of G = (V, E) is a graph with V’⊆ V and E’⊆ E"

"Let G = (V, E) be a graph. The neighbourhood, N(v), of a vertex v ∈ V, is the set of neighbours of v, i.e., N(v) = { u ∈ V | uv ∈ E }"

Comment: $\subseteq$ means "Is a subset of".  One has $A\subseteq B$ if and only if the following implication holds for every $a$:  $a\in A\implies a\in B$.  So for example, $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, and $C=\{0\}$.  One has the following:  $1\in A, 1\in B, 0\in B, 0\notin A, A\subseteq B, A\not\subseteq C$ etc... An important distinction: $0\in C$ and $\{0\}\subseteq C$ but $\{0\}\not\in C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\in\mathbb R$ means that $x$ **is a real number**.

$x\subseteq\mathbb R$ means that $x$ is a **set of real numbers**.

A set is something different from a real number, even if the set has real numbers as members. Even a set of *one* real number is not the same thing as that real number itself.

Answer (score 1):

The empty set is a subset of the empty set, but is not a member of the empty set.

The man holding a briefcase is a member of the set of men holding briefcases, but is not a subset of the set of men holding briefcases (the set with the man as one element is a subset, but a man is not a set) [a school example did a Venn diagram with briefcases, newspapers and umbrellas]